# Laravel DB - Comaparing 2 date columns by adding days on the other column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have a table called **finished_ca**

the table goes like this:

```
id    date_received        manufacturating_date  sample_status
1     2017-06-08T15:53     2017-07-05             1
2     2017-06-08T15:49     2017-08-01             2
```

If the sample_status = 1 the days that i have to add is 30
If the sample_status = 2 the days that i have to add is 14

Now I want to get all of the ids that the date_received is less than the manufacturing_date, if the sample_id is 1 the days that i have to add is 30, if it's 2 i will add 30

if it's written in a php language, it will look like this:

this is just an example tho.

`$days = sample_status == 1 ? 30 : 14;`

heres the query that I tried:

```
/*
I know that this will not work, but i want to parse the date first,
and add days depending on the sample_status
*/
$response_data = DB::table('finished_ca')
->where('date_received', '<=', Carbon::parse('manufacturing_date')->addDays(??));
```

Comment: Is this possible, have you already figured it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sr, i didn't read carefully
Here my update answer :D

`$response_data = DB::table('finished_ca')
                    ->where(function($query){
                         $query->where('sample_status', 1)
                        ->whereRaw('date(date_received) <=  DATE_ADD(manufacturing_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY)');
            })
                    ->orWhere(function($query){
                         $query->where('sample_status', 2)
                         ->whereRaw('date(date_received) <=  DATE_ADD(manufacturing_date, INTERVAL 14 DAY)');
                })->get();`

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, I'm doing a select statement, i don't need to update the data.

Comment: Hi, I think it works but i need to make some tests first before i set this as the accepted answer, thanks bro!